# Как правильно реализовать ?

Tags: php, mysql

Только начинаю изучать php/mysql поэтому столкнулся кое с какой проблемой.

Есть:

**index.php**

```
<?
include('themes/header.php');
include('themes/main.php');
include('themes/footer.php');
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1251">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <?
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            $id=mysql_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']));
            require ("php/mysql_connect.php");
            $query = "SELECT Title, Descriptions, Keywords FROM `news` WHERE Id='$id'";
            $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            echo'
                <title>'.$row['Title'].'</title>
                <meta name="description" content="'.$row['Descriptions'].'">
                <meta name="keywords" content="'.$row['Keywords'].'">       
            ';
            mysql_close();
        }
        ?>
    </head>
```

**main.php**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="flash">
            <?
            require ("php/mysql_connect.php");
            $query = "SELECT Id, Title FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
            $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo'<h1><a href = "index.php?id='.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Title'].'</a></h1>';
            }
            mysql_close();
            if (isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id=mysql_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']));
                require ("php/mysql_connect.php");
                $query = "SELECT Text FROM `news` WHERE Id='$id'";
                $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
                    echo'<p>'.$row['Text'].'</p>';
                mysql_close();
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <? include('themes/adsense.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

**footer.php**

```
</html>
```

Так вот, на главной ссылки на записи выводятся норм, а в main.php (сам пост) выводятся все title, а не этой записи. Если добавить WHERE Id='$id', тогда записи не выводятся на главной странице.

Посоветуйте как исправить и как вообще лучше реализовать ?

Comment: Чувак, ты делаешь слишком много подключений: require ("php/mysql_connect.php");

Во-первых, замени require на require_once. Во-вторых, подключения достаточно только в хидере. Один раз)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>>и как вообще лучше реализовать
```

Ну, начнем с самого начала.

1) Не рекомендуется использовать сокращения php тегов "`<?`", чаще данная опция не включена по умолчанию, что создаст проблему при переезде проекта на другой сервер. И не только поэтому.

1) Включение и выполнение указанного файла `include`. Для избежания повторного включения файла (проследить это в разросшихся проектах может быть проблематично), предпочтительнее использовать `include_once`. И необходимо понимать, что при неудачном включении файла, критического исключения сгенерировано не будет. То есть пользователь увидит на экране совсем не то, что ожидал. В таких случаях лучше все-таки останавливать дальнейшую работу скрипта, для чего используется `require_once`.

2) php_mysql - устаревший модуль, не рекомендуется его использовать, посмотрите в сторону mysqli или PDO.

3) Не совсем понятно для чего необходимо разбивать простую страницу на такие мелкие части. Из примера понятно, что необходимо менять только содержание между тегами "`<head></head>`", "`<body></body>`", ну так и меняйте его. И совершенно не обязательно использовать для этого include, для частичных изменений страницы чаще используют javascript, или тот же iframe, если у пользователя вдруг js отключен.

5) Я так понимаю, что Id - текстовое поле, что тоже не совсем правильно. Сложнее обрабатывать, медленнее поиск.

6) Саму задачу желательно словами описать так, чтобы ее смог реализовать любой программист, даже не заглядывая в ваши исходники. Попробуйте описать именно то, что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге; а не то, что у вас не работает.

....

Comment: `<?=` - c php 5.4 работает не зависимо от значения директивы `short_open_tag`.

Comment: Хорошо, исправил, спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: <? на 5.4.19 у меня ругалось что небыло открываемого php

Comment: @rusbaron, логично. "<?" и "<?=" ни одно и тоже. "<?=$string; ?>" - эквивалент "<?php echo $string; ?>".